# Find which package a data set is included in

Tags: r

Is there anyway that I can find which package a particular dataset belongs to? For example, which package does the dataset "UScereal" belong?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I like [Rseek](http://rseek.org/).

Comment: I suspect that some of the answers will only find datasets in packages *that are installed on your machine*. Was that the intent of your question? Or do you also look for datasets in non-installed packages?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what the `find()` function is for.

```
> find("iris")
[1] "package:datasets"

> find("UScereal")
[1] "package:MASS"
```

If an object is in the search path, `find()` will tell you where it came from. See `?find` for more information.

To get more information about a specific dataset, you can also use `?UScereal`, which will work if `UScereal` is in the search path, or `??UScereal` if it isn't but its parent package is installed.

To locate a dataset that isn't within an installed package, you can search for it on [RDocumentation.org](http://www.rdocumentation.org).

Comment: this is great, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can try `??UScerial`. This will search all help files and documentation for strings matching "UScerial" and tell you which package it is from. For example on my machine I get `MASS::UScereal`.

(This won't work if the package is not installed on your machine, but it will work if it is installed on your machine but not loaded.)

Answer (score 3):

One way is to pull off the datasets database for all your installed packages and then query that for the data you are looking for.

```
x <- data(package = .packages(all.available = TRUE))$results
x[grep("UScereal",x[,"Item"]),]
                                              Package 
                                               "MASS" 
                                              LibPath 
                 "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library" 
                                                 Item 
                                           "UScereal" 
                                                Title 
"Nutritional and Marketing Information on US Cereals"
```

Clearly this requires that you have installed the package. If you haven't, then you would have to search on the web for the correct package.